# If mt_rand() is run at the same moment, will the result be the same?

Tags: php, random

I am writing a PHP script to handle file upload to server. To prevent overwriting when there are files with the same name, the program will rename each uploaded file to the current timestamp.

However, this is not enough. In peak hour, there may be files that are uploaded at the same second. To make sure the uploaded files will have different file names, I am thinking of adding a random number at the end of the timestamp.

Then, I read from [the official PHP page on srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php)

> Note: There is no need to seed the random number generator with
>   srand() or mt_srand() as this is done automatically.

I guess they are using the timestamp for `srand()`. If 2 files are uploaded at the same second, so the timestamp for `srand()`, will the random result be the same? If yes, is there a way I can make sure the name is not duplicated even if they are uploaded at the same second?

Comment: as an aside: if youre not hooked on using `srand`/`mt_rand`, perhaps having a look at some PHP randomness https://gist.github.com/tom--/35f8a029d77467559cf2 or a non-laravel required laravel package https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-uuid

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that generates the seeds

```
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((zend_long) (time(0) * GetCurrentProcessId())) ^ ((zend_long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg())))
#else
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((zend_long) (time(0) * getpid())) ^ ((zend_long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg())))
```

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/standard/php_rand.h#L69

So it's a combination of timestamp and process id AND a psuedorandom

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6053987bc27e8dede37f437193a5cad448f99bce/ext/standard/lcg.c#L45

> combinedLCG() returns a pseudo random number in the range of (0, 1).
>    The function combines two CGs with periods of
>    2^31 - 85 and 2^31 - 249. The period of this function
>    is equal to the product of both primes.

So, i'd say you can rest assured they will not match.

Answer (score 2):

PHP has some better random functions too, like [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) and [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php). These will return a guaranteed unique value. Pass it to [`bin2hex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and you're all set!

Answer (score 1):

No, `seed` will be used for random numbers range, not for single number. Than you will be presented single number of that random-generated range. There is still possibility, that you will get same pseudo-random number.

Try adding something like `md5(time().$filename.'.'.$extension)` instead.

Comment: I understand that there is still a possibility of having the same filename, but the possibility should be small enough considering the range of random number. The possibility of having the same random result should be similar to having same filename for the 2 files uploaded at the same second.

Comment: same second is AEONS in computer speak.... a second is 1000 milliseconds... that's already 1000 different possiblities in a timestamp. The chances that two files are written to disc at the very same millisecond are extremely slim. even in the case that they are, adding a random to it will solve that.